# How to bootstrap an AWS EC2 instance from on-premise chef workstation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, chef-infra

With the help of knife ec2 plugin I have created an instance in AWS.

```
knife ec2 server create -I ami-04763b3055de4860b -f t2.micro -Z us-east-1a -N testEC2 -x ubuntu --sudo --associate-public-ip
```

Now I want to bootstrap the instance to my on-premise chef server. How it can be done?

Here is the bootstrap commands i used,

```
knife bootstrap ec2-54-160-171-106.compute-1.amazonaws.com -N cheftest --ssh-user ubuntu --sudo --i ./.chef/ubuntu-7cff793ad2fb518fd916.pem --sudo
```

Comment: please read [knife bootstrap](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html) and [bootstrap a node](https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html) documenation. then share what did not work for you and is the issue you experience.

Comment: @Mr. Upon reading the documentation you mentioned, i found port 22 was not enabled in security group of my instance. 
"knife ec2 server create -I ami-04763b3055de4860b -f t2.micro -Z us-east-1a -N knifeNode -x ubuntu --sudo --associate-public-ip"
the above command worked perfectly and it does bootstrapping too but in the end i'm facing this issue.

"Failed to open TCP connection to testchefserver.gklocal.com:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)"

Comment: make sure that the node and the chef server security groups allow each other